# How to do an IF with an OR and an AND in an Excel cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to confirm the values ​​of a list using the following condition in Excel.

I've been researching how cycles were done but I couldn't solve it.

The if is this:

```
=IF((F3-F2>0,0277777777777778)OR(F2-F4>0,0277777777777778)AND(C2="ON");F2;"null";)
```

Comment: I think you need to restructure like so =if(and(or(a=b,b=c)),d=e),true,false)`  Is it a formula you want or VBA?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Okay, but what is the disposition of the conditions?
like this?

if (e (or (value for IF, value for OR), value for AND), true if, false if)

Comment: Look at the help file for using AND and OR in formula

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a way:

- `(F3-F2>0,0277777777777778)OR(F2-F4>0,0277777777777778)` equivalent `Application.Max([f3] - [f2], [f2] - [f4]) > value`

.

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim value As Double,a as variant
value = 0,0277777777777778
a = IIf(Application.Max([f3] - [f2], [f2] - [f4]) > value And [c2] = "ON", [f2], "null")
'or
'a = IIf((([f3] - [f2]) > value Or ([f2] - [f4]) > value) And [c2] = "ON", [f2], "null")
msgbox a
End Sub
```

Comment: But I want to apply it to the excel cell, because I have a program that already does this but I want to confirm the values ​​by hand

Comment: I couldn't help further because you are new, you could start ideas from there

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use that as a worksheet formula I think it should be:

`=IF(AND(OR(F3-F2>0,0277777777777778,F2-F4>0,0277777777777778),C2="ON"),F2,"NULL")`